# retrieving data from databases in C#

Tags: c#

am new to programming and right now am working in C#, well now am trying something. i created a database in ms access containing rows and columns of data. i also created a windows form application containing text boxes. what i want to do now is to write a code that collects each data from a single column and row in the database table and insert it into a each text box in the windows form.
this is what i did:

```
try 
{
    //...
    command.CommandText = "SELECT (Table1.matricule, Table1.name, Table1.department, Table1.specialty, Table1.session) FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.matricule)=[textBox6.Text]))";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    connection.Open();

    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Person p = new Person();

        textBox1.Text = reader["Table1.matricule"];
        textBox2.Text = reader["Table1.name"];
        textBox3.Text = reader["Table1.department"];
        textBox4.Text = reader["Table1.specialty"];
        textBox5.Text = reader["Table1.session"];

        personsList.Add(p);
    }
    return personsList;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add, what is the expected result.

Comment: Where is it failing?  Is there an exception thrown (and what is the message)?  Have you set your connection string properly?

Comment: Look at the example in the MSDN documentation using parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: One thing to note as pointed out in one of the answers below you should be using Parameterized Queries.  Also you instantiate a person object to the variable p but never set any of its properties, did you mean to do that?  Also I would instantiate your connection object outsite the try catch and tack on a finally to your try catch where you close the connection after its been opened inside the try catch.  This will ensure your connection is always closed in the event of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually set your parameter values in code as opposed to specifying them within your string :

```
// Parameterize the query
command.CommandText = "SELECT matricule, name, department, specialty, session FROM Table1 WHERE matricule = ?";
```

and then set your parameter prior to execution using the [`AddWithValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
connection.Open();
// Set your parameter prior to executing the query
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matricule",textBox6.Text);
// Now execute your query
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Finally, you likely need to be populating the properties on your `Person` objects as opposed to setting the textbox values (as the `Person` objects will be empty) :

```
 // Populate person properties within your loop
 Person p = new Person()
 {
      Matricule = reader["matricule"],
      Name = reader["name"],
      Department = reader["department"],
      Specialty = reader["specialty"],   
 }
```

**A Considered Refactor**

You can implement these changes along with a few others (including the use of `using` statements to ensure that objects are properly closed and disposed of) :

```
// Define your list of people
var people = new List<Person>();
// Create your connection
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection("{your-connection-string}"))
{
     try 
     {
         // Define your query (and parameters)
         var query = "SELECT matricule, name, department, specialty, session FROM Table1 WHERE matricule = ?";
         // Define a using statement
         using(var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
         {
             connection.Open();
             // Set your parameter prior to executing the query
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matricule",textBox6.Text);
             // Execute your query
             using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
             {
                  // While you have rows, read them
                  while(reader.Read())
                  {
                       people.Add(new Person()
                       {
                           Matricule = reader["matricule"],
                           Name = reader["name"],
                           Department = reader["department"],
                           Specialty = reader["specialty"],   
                      });
                  }
                  // Return your collection
                  return people;
             }
         }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         // Something blew up, handle accordingly
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things are wrong with the given code:

1.Use parameterised queries instead for plain text:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT matricule, name, department, specialty, session FROM Table1 WHERE matricule = ?";
connection.Open();
command.Parameters.Add("@matricule",OleDbType.VarChar).Value= textBox6.Text;
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

2.I cannot figure out why you are using `personsList` here:
If The expected query result will contains more than one rows, you will get only the last values are displayed on the textboxes. If it is not multiple rows you need to add details to the person object.

```
personsList.Add(new Person()
 {
      Matricule = reader["matricule"],
      Name = reader["name"],
      Department = reader["department"],
      Specialty = reader["specialty"],   
 });
```

3.You need not to use `Table1.` every time while accessing values from the reader object. simply you can read them using:

```
 textBox1.Text = reader["matricule"];
 // load rest of textboxes
```

4.The whole things will looks like the following:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@matricule",OleDbType.VarChar).Value= textBox6.Text;
connection.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   textBox1.Text = reader["matricule"];
   textBox2.Text = reader["name"];
   textBox3.Text = reader["department"];
   textBox4.Text = reader["specialty"];
   textBox5.Text = reader["session"];
   personsList.Add(new Person()
     {
          Matricule = reader["matricule"],
          Name = reader["name"],
          Department = reader["department"],
          Specialty = reader["specialty"],   
     });
}
```